# AAPT2 error: check logs for details in android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, aapt2

I'm just learning android studio and getting this error and am unable to resolve. I can't even get what the problem is related with. (all other applications are working properly).I tried some other solutions from stackoverflow but none resolves my issue....

Any explanations???

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: not well-formed (invalid token).","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\*************\AndroidStudioProjects\myapp\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml","position":{"startLine":25}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

error: not well-formed (invalid token).
Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: not well-formed (invalid token)., sources=[C:\Users*************\AndroidStudioProjects\myapp\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:26], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}

Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Comment: Aapt errors can come from a number of reasons.. Looks like this time it is in activity_main.xml ... Could you paste both activity main xml and java class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that your file `activity_main.xml` is not well-formed - that means it's probably missing a closing tag or similar, making it an invalid XML file.